# SQL SERVER 2005 STORE PROCEDURE RETURN VALUES(ARRAY or Without array parameter) TO PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, arrays, stored-procedures

I have googled alot about this topic and found only one website describing about this http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html but unable find its solution according to my scenerio.

I am using php to retrieve the values from sql server database using store procedure.I have two stored procedures.One sp have parameters with single value in them.The other sp have a parameter with an array.Unable to return the values of both in php.but when i exec it in query editor of sql srver then it works fine and give me the results.First see my first sp with single value parameter.then i'll explain what i am doing and the problem.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE getStoryid (@storyid AS varchar(18), @nstoryid AS NVARCHAR(30),
                            @ntypeid AS NVARCHAR(30))
 AS
 Declare @sql AS nvarchar(MAX)
 SET @sql = 'SELECT es.storyid, es.userid, es.catid, es.heading, es.isapproved, 
             es.coverpic, es.story, es.created from et_stories es 
             where es.storyid = ' + @storyid
             if (@ntypeid !=3)
             SET @sql=  @sql + 'and es.userid = ' + @nstoryid
             EXEC(@sql)
 GO
```

when i EXECUTE it like this

```
EXEC getStoryid '1','9' ,'3'
```

then it give me the result in sql server editor but shows error when i call this procedure from php

this is my php code

```
$sql = "EXEC getStoryid '".  $storyid ."','". $nstoryid ."' ,'". $ntypeid ."'"; 
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

The Second sp for array parameter is same but i am passing array on my $storyid parameter or @storyid parameter

Please tell me any easy solution to get the values from db using php or i think any return function may be there in sqlsrver 2005.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this [Mssql Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php)

```
$link = mssql_connect($server, '$user', '$pass');
if (!$link) {
   die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
mssql_select_db('dbname', $link);

$stmt = mssql_init('[getStoryid]');

$storyid = 1;
$nstoryid = 9;
$ntypeid = 3;

// Bind the field names
mssql_bind($stmt, '@storyid ',  $storyid,  SQLINT2,  false,  false);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@nstoryid',  $nstoryid, SQLINT2,  false,  false);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ntypeid ',  $ntypeid,  SQLINT2,  false,  false);

// Execute
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);

// Free statement
mssql_free_statement($stmt);

$array=array();
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[] = $row;
}

mssql_close($link);   

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

It's important you read this chapter [Requirements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php)